# API Gateway Options method throwing 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a `Custom Authorizer` with `API Gateway`. When deployed through `SAM Module` it also creates `Options Method` when you enable `CORS`. The thing I really don't understand is why the custom authorizer gets attached to `Options` endpoint? [image]

This is throwing `403` when I try to call the endpoint from browser and works perfectly fine when I remove `Authorization` from the `Options` method.

[image]

Below is the `template.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'*'"
      AllowHeaders: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"

Resources:
  TestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: testAuthoriser
        Authorizers:
          testAuthoriser:
            FunctionArn:
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub test-custom-autoriser
            Identity:
              Header: Authorization
              ValidationExpression: ^Bearer [-0-9a-zA-Z\._]*$
              ReauthorizeEvery: 30 

  Version:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: test
      CodeUri: src/test
      Handler: index.test
      Events:
        EndPoint:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref TestApi
            Path: /test
            Method: get
            Auth:
              Authorizer: testAuthoriser
```

I have enabled the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` in header as well. Not sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: hey did you manage to figure out how to remove the authorizer from the `Options` method?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer, see the aws sam issue [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/717)

```yaml
 Api:
    Cors:
      AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization'" 
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
      Authorizers:
        CognitoAuthorizer:
          UserPoolArn: yourUserPool
      AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: False // <== this line
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you're setting a DefaultAuthorizer and are also using the Cors property, then the OPTIONS method of the API for Cors Preflight will be using that default authorizer.  You probably don't want this since your browser likely won't properly handle authorization for those calls to OPTIONS.

See the [AWS SAM documentation on this topic.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html#sam-api-apiauth-adddefaultauthorizertocorspreflight)

Answer (score 0):

For CORS, AWS API Gateway will always enable OPTIONS method to allow preflight test. You can read more on that in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

The reason you are seeing preflight error in your browser because 403 Forbidden is coming from your Custom Authorizer. Custom Authorizer do not return headers so you will always see preflight error if request is rejected by Custom Authorzer.

To debug this, log the Policy your Custom Authorizer is returning. You can then see that in CloudWatch. Policy must contain Allow statement for the Resource being requested.

Comment: Policy does contain the Allow statement - 
```{
  "principalId": "",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:RemaingArn"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "scope": "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
  }
}```

As mentioned if authorization removed off the OPTIONS everything work as expected

Comment: I would suggest populate `principalId` with userId. Also not sure why `context` is there in the policy as it does not serve any purpose from custom authorizer point of view. Try remove it. Finally ensure `RemainArn` do match with the actual resource. You can try with wildcard just for test `arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*`

Comment: I tried the above suggestion but the same problem. I believe its API Gateway causing the issue.

Comment: Similar to this one `https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer`